# Javascript сортировка товаров по цене

Tags: html, массивы, сортировка

Подскажите как реализовать сортировку по цене.

Выбираю по `ClassName .appartments-item__price'.`

Получаю массив. Сортировать  методом `sort`.  Тут уже выдает ошибку что `unexpected token { на строке prices.sort(a, b).`

А как потом сослаться на `.appartments-item`, чтобы карточки выстроились по новому?

Это же тоже надо учитывать при сортировке?

```js
document.querySelector('.sorting__price').onclick = function() {
  let prices = document.getElementsByClassName('.appartments-item__price');
  prices.sort(a, b) {
    if (a > b)
      return -1;
    if (a < b)
      return 1;
    if (a == b)
      return 0;
  };
};
```

```html
<article class="appartments-item" tabindex="0">
  <h2 class="appartments-item__title">Студия №44</h2>
  <div class="appartments-item__price">5 000 000 руб</div>
  <footer class="appartments-item__footer  appartments-footer">
    <span class="appartments-footer__text--free">Свободно</span>
    <span class="appartments-footer__text--reserved">Забронировано</span>
  </footer>
  <div class="appartments-item__star"></div>
</article>

<article class="appartments-item" tabindex="0">
  <h2 class="appartments-item__title">Однокомнатная №666</h2>
  <div class="appartments-item__price">16 000 000 руб</div>
  <footer class="appartments-item__footer  appartments-footer">
    <span class="appartments-footer__text--free">Свободно</span>
    <span class="appartments-footer__text--reserved">Забронировано</span>
  </footer>
  <div class="appartments-item__star"></div>
</article>
```

Comment: Даже и приблизительно не должно работать

Comment: Тег `<footer>` на странице может быть только в единственном экземпляре...  Так же как  теги `<header>, <main>`

Comment: @Air это не так.... Footer также можно вкладывать в section и в atricle

Comment: Ну-Ну.... можно так можно...

Comment: @Air почему нельзя? Если в документации сказано, что можно, то почему нет? Если вы думайте, что теги footer и header сделали чтобы верх и них страницы обрамлять, то вы ошибаетесь.

Comment: @Air https://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-footer-element  Читаем документацию и не выдумывате ничего из головы.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, я же не возражаю... Можно значит можно...  Вполне могло измениться правило...  Я не читал давно... Раньше было нельзя точно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.sorting__price').addEventListener("click", () => {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.appartments-item');
  const sorted = [...elements].sort((a, b) => {
    const priceElA = a.querySelector(".appartments-item__price");
    const priceElB = b.querySelector(".appartments-item__price");
    const getPrice = (el) => parseInt(el.innerHTML.replace(/ /g, ""));
    return getPrice(priceElA) - getPrice(priceElB);
  });
  const resultEl = document.querySelector(".results-container");
  resultEl.innerHTML = null;
  sorted.forEach(el => resultEl.appendChild(el));
});
```

```css
.results-container {
  background-color: #ffddcc;
}
```

```html
<button class="sorting__price">Sort</button>
<article class="appartments-item" tabindex="0">
  <h2 class="appartments-item__title">Однокомнатная №666</h2>
  <div class="appartments-item__price">16 000 000 руб</div>
  <footer class="appartments-item__footer  appartments-footer">
    <span class="appartments-footer__text--free">Свободно</span>
    <span class="appartments-footer__text--reserved">Забронировано</span>
  </footer>
  <div class="appartments-item__star"></div>
</article>

<article class="appartments-item" tabindex="0">
  <h2 class="appartments-item__title">Студия №44</h2>
  <div class="appartments-item__price">5 000 000 руб</div>
  <footer class="appartments-item__footer  appartments-footer">
    <span class="appartments-footer__text--free">Свободно</span>
    <span class="appartments-footer__text--reserved">Забронировано</span>
  </footer>
  <div class="appartments-item__star"></div>
</article>

<div class="results-container"></div>
```

Если игнорировать семантику HTML с несколькими `<footer>` обернутыми в `<article>`, то чисто JS должен быть примерно таким:

1. Event listeners лучше всего добавлять с помощью `addEventListener`, так как при этом Вы не удаляете остальные listeners, как в случае `el.onclick = func`
2. Если взялись использовать `querySelector`, то используйте его везде и не смешивайте с `getElement` методами без лишней необходимости. Разницы (почти) никакой, вопрос в читабельности.
3. Когда Вы получаете елементы после выборки, они не являются массивом, а являются HTMLCollection, следовательно не имеют методов массивов, таких как: `forEach`, `map`, `sort`, etc. Чтобы добавить их, достаточно использовать деструктуризацию `[...elements]`.
4. Как правильно заметил @dev_null - *sort принимает один аргумент, функцию, определяющую порядок сортировки.*, поэтому читайте документацию.

Comment: Ваш код работает, но, к сожалению, выстраивает только в возрастающем порядке. На второе нажатие никак не реагирует. Не подскажите как дополнить код? И благодарю за комментарии.

Comment: Убрал только resultEl.innerHTML = null; Иначе кнопка сортировки пропадает.

Answer (score 0):

sort принимает один аргумент, функцию, определяющую порядок сортировки. Пруфы [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
function callback(evt) {

  var list = document.getElementById('wrapper');

  var items = list.childNodes;
  var itemsArr = [];
  for (var i in items) {
    if (items[i].nodeType == 1) {
      itemsArr.push(items[i]);
    }
  }

  itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.getAttribute('price')) == parseFloat(b.getAttribute('price')) ?
      0 :
      (parseFloat(a.getAttribute('price')) > parseFloat(b.getAttribute('price')) ? 1 : -1);
  });

  for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
    list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
  }
}

document.getElementById('sort').addEventListener('click', callback);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <article class="appartments-item" tabindex="0" price="5000000">
    <h2 class="appartments-item__title">Студия №44</h2>
    <div class="appartments-item__price">5 000 000 руб</div>
    <footer class="appartments-item__footer  appartments-footer">
      <span class="appartments-footer__text--free">Свободно</span>
      <span class="appartments-footer__text--reserved">Забронировано</span>
    </footer>
    <div class="appartments-item__star"></div>
  </article>

  <article class="appartments-item" tabindex="0" price="16000000">
    <h2 class="appartments-item__title">Однокомнатная №666</h2>
    <div class="appartments-item__price">16 000 000 руб</div>
    <footer class="appartments-item__footer  appartments-footer">
      <span class="appartments-footer__text--free">Свободно</span>
      <span class="appartments-footer__text--reserved">Забронировано</span>
    </footer>
    <div class="appartments-item__star"></div>
  </article>

  <article class="appartments-item" tabindex="0" price="5000">
    <h2 class="appartments-item__title">Студия №41</h2>
    <div class="appartments-item__price">5 000 руб</div>
    <footer class="appartments-item__footer  appartments-footer">
      <span class="appartments-footer__text--free">Свободно</span>
      <span class="appartments-footer__text--reserved">Забронировано</span>
    </footer>
    <div class="appartments-item__star"></div>
  </article>
</div>

<button id="sort">Sort</button>
```

Comment: Что за фильтрация по nodeType?

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach Дабы игнорировать текстовые ноды

Comment: Извращение еще то

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach Такое вот работающее извращение

Comment: Ваш код рабочий, благодарю! Но возможны решения без добавления атрибута 'price'.

Comment: @DaveGarrow я не совсем понимаю, это вопрос, или замечание ? `Но возможны решения без добавления атрибута 'price'.` Знака вопроса в конце вроде не видно

Comment: Нет, это не вопрос и не замечание. Просто есть варианты без атрибута.

Comment: @DaveGarrow на то оно и програмирование, вариантов реализации немало )